# Find the routes involving two buses that can go from A to B

Tags: mysql, sql

Question in SQL from sqlzoo:
Find the routes involving two buses that can go from Craiglockhart to Sighthill.
Show the bus no. and company for the first bus, the name of the stop for the transfer,
and the bus no. and company for the second bus.

This is the Code I found, however it won't work:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT  a.num, a.company, 
             trans1.name ,  c.num,  c.company
FROM route a JOIN route b
ON (a.company = b.company AND a.num = b.num)
JOIN ( route c JOIN route d ON (c.company = d.company AND c.num= d.num))
JOIN stops start ON (a.stop = start.id)
JOIN stops trans1 ON (b.stop = trans1.id)
JOIN stops trans2 ON (c.stop = trans2.id)
JOIN stops end ON (d.stop =  end.id)
WHERE  start.name = 'Craiglockhart' AND end.name = 'Sighthill'
            AND  trans1.name = trans2.name 
ORDER BY a.num ASC , trans1.name
```

[image: The Table]

Comment: So what does not work?

Comment: I find myself incapable of solving your problem, which can be more concisely explained by mentioning what error you're getting, and describing your table structures. Savvy?

Answer (score 2):

When you have big problems like that, the best practice is to partition it. Technically, all buses that departs `Craiglockhart` should eventually reach `Sighthill` with enough transfers, but we'll restrict ourselves to 1 transfer (because that's how the problem's worded).

So basically, you need to find a bus that departs from `Craiglockhart`, and a bus that arrives at `Sighthill`, and you need to find all intersecting stops between those.

The first 2 parts are incredibly easy (and you got that part right) :

```
SELECT DISTINCT num , company
FROM route
INNER JOIN stops ON stop = id
WHERE name='Craiglockhart'
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT num, company AS bus
FROM route
INNER JOIN stops ON stop = id
WHERE name='Sighthill'
```

From there, you have a list of all buses that departs `Craiglockhart` and all buses that arrives at `Sighthill`. You only remaining problem is finding where those 2 intersect.

The initial part of the solution is just as easy; You need to fetch the name of the 2 buses, as well as the name of the stop.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  r1.num as NoFrom, r1.company CoFrom, name,r2.num as NoTo, r2.company CoTo
```

Which means you have to query at least 3 tables

```
FROM stops
INNER JOIN route r1 ON r1.stop = id
INNER JOIN route r2 ON r2.stop = id
```

So now, you gathered a list of all possible transfers, you only need to filter out the useless ones. One suboptimal way to do it would be something like this :

```
WHERE exists(
    SELECT 1
    FROM route r3 
    INNER JOIN stops s1 ON r3.stop = s1.id
    WHERE s1.name='Craiglockhart' AND r3.num = r1.num AND r3.company = r1.company)

AND exists(
    SELECT 1
    FROM route r4 
    INNER JOIN stops s2 ON r4.stop = s2.id
    WHERE s1.name='Sighthill' AND r4.num = r2.num AND r4.company = r2.company)
```

So basically one way to do it would be :

```
SELECT DISTINCT r1.num as NoFrom, r1.company CoFrom, name, r2.num as NoTo, r2.company CoTo
FROM stops
INNER JOIN route r1 ON r1.stop = id
INNER JOIN route r2 ON r2.stop = id
WHERE exists(
    SELECT 1
    FROM route r3 
    INNER JOIN stops s1 ON r3.stop = s1.id
    WHERE s1.name='Craiglockhart' AND r3.num = r1.num AND r3.company = r1.company)
AND exists(
    SELECT 1
    FROM route r4 
    INNER JOIN stops s2 ON r4.stop = s2.id
    WHERE s2.name='Sighthill' AND r4.num = r2.num AND r4.company = r2.company)
```

[Relevant SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fdf80)

One thing worth noting though is that I used "WHERE EXISTS(...)" when your exercise clearly implies that you should be using self joins. I won't give you the whole answer if you're trying to learn, so have a go at it and try to convert it into self joins ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT S.num, S.company, S.name, T.num, T.company 
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT a.num, a.company, sb.name 
     FROM route a JOIN route b ON (a.num = b.num and a.company = b.company) 
                  JOIN stops sa ON sa.id = a.stop 
                  JOIN stops sb ON sb.id = b.stop 
     WHERE sa.name = 'Craiglockhart' AND sb.name <> 'Craiglockhart'
)S

JOIN

    (SELECT x.num, x.company, sy.name 
     FROM route x JOIN route y ON (x.num = y.num and x.company = y.company) 
                  JOIN stops sx ON sx.id = x.stop 
                  JOIN stops sy ON sy.id = y.stop 
     WHERE sx.name = 'Lochend' AND sy.name <> 'Lochend'
    )T

ON (S.name = T.name)
ORDER BY S.num, S.name, T.num
```

Comment: Better to add explanations or comments into your solution.

Comment: The first temp result, 'S' was a look for every stop that is reached from Craiglockhart. The second one, 'T,' is similar but all stops hit from Lochend. The results are joined with the 'ON' saying connect where the stops from Craiglockhart match those from Lochend, and that's your route. Finally, with the join on 'S' and 'T' get the numbers, companies, and the the name of the stop where you transfer. It's pretty clever.

Answer (score 1):

Find the routes involving two buses that can go from Craiglockhart to Lochend.
Show the bus no. and the company for the first bus, the name of the stop for the transfer,
and the bus no. and the company for the second bus.
Hint:
Self-join twice to find buses that visit Craiglockhart and Lochend, then join those on matching stops.

```
SELECT DISTINCT one.num as FirstBus, one.company as FirstComp, one.name as Transfer, two.num as SecBus, two.company as SecComp

FROM

    (select distinct a.num, a.company, yy.name
     from route a join route b on (a.company=b.company and a.num=b.num) 
                  join stops xx on (xx.id=a.stop) 
                  join stops yy on (yy.id=b.stop)
     where xx.name='Craiglockhart' and yy.name<>'Lochend'
     ) AS one

JOIN

    (select distinct c.num, d.company, mm.name
     from route c join route d on (c.company=d.company and c.num=d.num) 
                  join stops mm on (mm.id=c.stop) 
                  join stops nn on (nn.id=d.stop)
     where mm.name <> 'Craiglockhart' and nn.name='Lochend'
     ) AS two

ON (two.name=one.name)
```

LOGIC:
1. find the num and company for the ones who have 'Craiglockhart' but not 'Lochend';
2. find the num and company for the ones who have 'Lochend' but not 'Craiglockhart';
3. find the shared stops from the two above-- using the table "stops" as the link;
4. display as required.
Hope helps!

Comment: The <> conditions aren't necessary as there are no direct routes. One can add the following to get the answer to match on SQLZOO: order by FirstBus,Transfer,SecBus

Answer (score 1):

```
with p as (
select a.num,a.company,a.stop ,b.stop as des from route a join route b on a.num=b.num and a.company = b.company and a.stop = 53),
q as
(select a.num,a.company,a.stop as des,b.stop from route a join route b on a.num=b.num and a.company = b.company and b.stop = 147)
select p.num,p.company,r.name,q.num,q.company from p join q on p.des = q.des
join stops r on r.id = p.des order by p.num,r.name,q.num
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that a route consists simply of a start (which is the `pos` attribute) and an end, which is the `stop` attribute. Hopefully this points you in the right direction. The outer query gets all the routes that start in Craiglockhart, and the inner query gets all the routes that end in Sighthill, then you join the two where the first route's end is the same as the second route's start.

```
    SELECT r1.Num     AS FirstBusNo,
           r1.Company AS FirstBusCompany,
           Stops.Name AS Transfer,
           r2.Num     AS SecondBusNo, 
           r2.Company AS SecondBusCompany
      FROM Route r1
INNER JOIN Stops trans 
        ON r1.Stop = trans.Id
INNER JOIN ( SELECT Num, Company, Pos
             FROM Route, Stops
             WHERE Id = stop
             AND Name = 'Sighthill' ) r2
        ON r1.stop = r2.pos
     WHERE Stops.Name = 'Craiglockhart';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct  a.num,a.company, stopb.name,  second.num, second.company
FROM route a JOIN route b ON
  (a.company=b.company AND a.num=b.num)
  JOIN stops stopa ON (a.stop=stopa.id)
  JOIN stops stopb ON (b.stop=stopb.id)
  JOIN 
(
SELECT distinct  stopaa.name, aa.num, aa.company
FROM route aa JOIN route bb ON
  (aa.company=bb.company AND aa.num=bb.num)
  JOIN stops stopaa ON (aa.stop=stopaa.id)
  JOIN stops stopbb ON (bb.stop=stopbb.id)
  where stopbb.name ='Lochend'
) second on stopb.name = second.name
WHERE stopa.name='Craiglockhart'
```

Comment: Please can you explain why this code is the correct answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Hint "Self-join twice to find buses that visit Craiglockhart and Lochend, then join those on matching stops."

First, finding the stops that can reach from stopa = 'Craiglockhart'. 
Second, finding the stops that can reach to stopb='Lochend'. 
Then JOIN the matching stops.

```
Select first.num, first.company, first.name, second.num, second.company
From
    (Select Distinct a.num, a.company, stopb.name
    From route a JOIN route b ON (a.num=b.num AND a.company=b.company)
                 JOIN stops stopa ON stopa.id=a.stop
                 JOIN stops stopb ON stopb.id=b.stop
    Where stopa.name='Craiglockhart') first
JOIN
    (Select Distinct a.num, a.company, stopa.name
    From route a JOIN route b ON (a.num=b.num AND a.company=b.company)
                 JOIN stops stopa ON stopa.id=a.stop
                 JOIN stops stopb ON stopb.id=b.stop
    Where stopb.name='Lochend') second
Where first.name=second.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Note : The idea is to bypass this problem :

Any [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZgLJ.png)first line, proceeding from the can reach all sites, this is the transfer station, in operation in the route to find all lines through the site, find out after John Locke will have to line although not stating the subject, but the right answer will be ordered by line number, transfer station

```
SELECT a.num, a.company,  stops.name,  d.num, d.company
FROM route a JOIN route b ON a.company = b.company AND a.num = b.num
JOIN stops ON b.stop = stops.id
JOIN route c ON c.stop = stops.id
JOIN route d ON c.company = d.company AND c.num = d.num
WHERE a.stop = (SELECT id FROM stops WHERE name = 'Craiglockhart')
AND d.stop = (SELECT id FROM stops WHERE name = 'Lochend')
ORDER BY a.num, stops.name, d.num
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1;

WITH sel1 AS (SELECT r1.num, r1.company, s2.name transferstop
FROM route r1
JOIN route r2 ON (r1.num=r2.num AND r1.company=r2.company)
JOIN stops s1 ON s1.id=r1.stop
JOIN stops s2 ON s2.id=r2.stop
WHERE s1.name = 'Craiglockhart'), 

sel2 AS (SELECT s1.name transferstop, r2.num, r2.company
FROM route r1
JOIN route r2 ON (r1.num=r2.num AND r1.company=r2.company)
JOIN stops s1 ON s1.id=r1.stop
JOIN stops s2 ON s2.id=r2.stop
WHERE s2.name = 'Lochend')

SELECT sel1.num, sel1.company, sel1.transferstop, sel2.num, sel2.company
  FROM sel1
  JOIN sel2 ON sel1.transferstop=sel2.transferstop
 ORDER BY 1,3,4
```

Answer (score 0):

The assumption based on the structure is that all the stations in a route are connected i.e. we need to expect that pos 2 can be reached from pos 9 in a given route stop and num.

Schema: `route(num, company, pos, stop)`

```
with from_to_stop as
(
select
distinct a.stop as from_stop, a.num, a.company, b.stop as to_stop
from
route a
join route b
on a.num = b.num
and a.company = b.company
)

select
fts1.num, fts1.company, fts1_name.name as transfer, fts2.num, fts2.company
from
(select * from from_to_stop where from_stop = 53) fts1
join (select * from from_to_stop where to_stop = 147) fts2
on fts1.to_stop = fts2.from_stop
join stops fts1_name on fts1_name.id = fts1.to_stop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.num, a.company, stops.name, c.num, c.company FROM route a
JOIN route b ON a.num=b.num AND a.company=b.company AND a.stop=53
JOIN route c ON a.num<>c.num AND c.stop=b.stop
JOIN route d ON c.num=d.num AND c.company=d.company AND d.stop=147
JOIN stops ON c.stop=stops.id
```

Passes when Microsoft SQL is the selected engine.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT 
    r1.num, 
    r1.company, 
    s2.name, 
    r4.num, 
    r4.company
FROM 
    route r1 
JOIN 
    route r2 ON (r1.company = r2.company AND r1.num = r2.num)
JOIN 
    route r3 ON (r2.stop = r3.stop)
JOIN 
    route r4 ON (r3.company = r4.company AND r3.num = r4.num)
JOIN 
    stops s1 ON (r1.stop = s1.id)
JOIN 
    stops s2 ON (r2.stop = s2.id)
JOIN 
    stops s3 ON (r3.stop = s3.id)
JOIN 
    stops s4 ON (r4.stop = s4.id)
WHERE 
    s1.name = 'Craiglockhart' AND 
    s4.name = 'Lochend'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).